# How to convert object list json model?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, type-conversion, jsonconvert

I want to send a JSON model to the front as follows:

Here it is:

```
{
    "2020-01-22":1,
    "2020-01-23":2,
    "2020-01-24":3,
    ..
}
```

I have data that I pulled through the database. Here is my class for the list of objects:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    public int? Data { get; set; }
}
```

I fill my list using this model and send it to the front side as JSON.

```
{
   "dateTime": "2020-01-22",
   "data": 1
},
{
   "dateTime": "2020-01-23",
   "data": 2
}, 
    ..
```

How can I create the JSON model I originally defined? The programming language I use is C# and .NET Core.

Comment: have you tried `Dictionary<DateTime,int>`?

Comment: No I haven't tried. I don't know how to try?

Comment: I don't recommend to use datetime format, best way to use unix timestamp or 
model as 
{
datetime:{
"day":22,
"month":1,
"year":2020
},
data:{}
}
You'll have troublewith converting string to datetime in a future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put your variables in Dictionary and serialize you will get the JSON you want. You can try it here https://dotnetfiddle.net/dmepqX

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myDic = new Dictionary<DateTime,int>();
        myDic.Add(DateTime.Now,1);
        var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDic);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to set the `DateFormatString` if you only want the date part and not the time: `var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd" };  var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDic, settings);`